# How do I call this parameter in another class?

Tags: java, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm trying to call the static method `getPod` in the class `DropPod` from another class with `DropPod.getPod()` except I need a parameter for `DropPod.getPod()`.
How do I change the `getPod` method so I can access it from the other class?

I know I could just make land() static, but I don't want to do that. I'd like to try to learn to do it this way.

```
public class DropPod {

    protected static boolean opened;
    int pos = Random.NormalIntRange(1777, 1794);

    public static void getPod(DropPod drop)
    {
        drop.land();
    } 

    public void land() {
        Level.set(pos, Terrain.DROPPOD_CLOSED);
        Game.updateMap(pos);
        opened = false;
        Dungeon.observe();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make a new variable that stores an instance of the class

Comment: Just make a new instance of DropPod in the other class.

Comment: Thanks guys! I didn't understand that I should be doing that in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: You can create a new instance of DropPod in your other class. With this instance, you can just call Object.getPod().

Option 2: You already mentioned this, but you could make land a static method as well and DropPod.getPod() should work.

Comment: Ahh, I understand now. It wasn't clicking before. So I just add                      DropPod dropPod = new DropPod();
                    dropPod.land();

Comment: Thank you! It's a dumb question I asked, so I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods of a class cannot reference non-static methods of its objects.
If you only want 1 instance of DropPod, you can add it as a property of it's own class. Something like a [Singleton Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Add a non-static overload for `getPod()` with no parameters, that just calls `land()`.

Maybe remove the static version completely. Hard to see why this method exists at all actually, or why it is called `getPod()` when it doesn't return anything. I would remove it and just call `land()` directly.

Also hard to see why you want to call a method that calls `land()` when you don't have anything to land. You need to rethink all this.